# Janky shadows on objects in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to smooth out the shadows on the objects in my scene

Here is a img : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISYn8.jpg

and my Github : https://github.com/mat148/shoeVR

Here is some of the code that pertains to the shadows:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

firePillar.castShadow = true;
firePillar.receiveShadow = true;

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x007c9a, 0.5);
directionalLight.position.set(500, 704, 0);
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
```

Comment: you want to play with the `shadowBias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadows are extremely hard to get correct. Since you need to consider which meshes are creating shadows and if they receive shadows and so on.

ShadowBias is something to play with for sure.

Try

```
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
//Your shadow casting light source
spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.shadowBias = - 0.001;
// This increases the resolution of your Shadow maps. 
spotlight.shadowMapWidth = 2042;
spotlight.shadowMapHeight = 2042;
```

Comment: What is shadowBias for? when i make it negative, my shadows will disappear. And make it > 0 do not change anything?!